# Queries between the timestamp_start to the previous timestamp_finish sql

Tags: sql, metabase

I'm work with Metabase queries and i facing this issues .

database : Session_Histories

Makes sure that the distance between the `timestamp_start` to the previous `timestamp_finish` of the same user, OS, and app version is more than 15 minutes

I try to write this query in Metabase but still not work :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Total_Data
FROM `Session_Histories`
WHERE DATE(Timestamp_Start)
AND DATE(Timestamp_Ends) > (INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

:) what's wrong guys ?

Comment: 1. Tag your database 2) provide sample data and desired output

Comment: database table : Session_Histories ( Timestamp_Start, Timestamp_Ends ,OS , App_version , User_id )